# iOS app searching large amounts of text

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, search

I apologize if this is a repeat, but I honestly have done my best to research this and haven't come up with much.

I'm making an iPad reference app that will make several large textbooks searchable (maybe 3-4k pages in total). It's a fairly simple idea: the user can choose any combination of texts to search, put in his term, and the app will find those terms in all the texts and return them, indexed in a table view.

The view controller has a series of switches, the value of which get read by a method into an NSSet and passed to the search controller. That part works.

I have a SearchController class which the view controller instantiates and calls a method on:

```
-(void)performSearchWithString:(NSString *)searchString andTexts:(NSSet *)texts
{
for (id book in texts) {
    if ([book isEqual:kBook1]){
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"neiJing" withExtension:@"txt"];
        NSString *text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&error];
        [text enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])
                                 options:NSStringEnumerationByWords
                              usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                                  NSRange found = [substring rangeOfString:text];
                                  if (found.location != NSNotFound) {
                                      NSLog(@"%@", substring);
                                  } else {
                                      NSLog(@"Not found");
                                  }
                              }];
    }
```

I seem to have succeeded in enumerating through every word in all the texts, but no return values are found so I just get a never-ending stream of "Not found".

I inserted a test phrase into each text that I know for certain to be there, but it's not coming up.

I have a feeling I'm going about this all wrong. Even if I made this work, the performance hit might be too big for a useable app...I'm still trying to wrap my head around blocks, too. I just haven't found any ready-baked solutions out there for searching large volumes of text and picking out results. If anyone has any hints or references to an open-source library that I might adapt, I would be very grateful.

Comment: How many textbooks do you know of that contain a decoded URL?  Because that's what you're comparing to.

Comment: NSLog(@"text: %@", text);

Comment: I see a retain cycle.  No need to compute the found NSRange.

Comment: CodaFi: No, the URL is just to grab the text from the app bundle. That part works: I can pull up a whole text in the debugger if I want.

Comment: bneely: That would just log the whole text, not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're searching for the whole text inside of each substring passed to the block.  This line is the problem (and causes a retain cycle):

```
NSRange found = [substring rangeOfString:text];
```

The code needs to look for something it can find:

```
NSString *findMe = @"A string we expect to find";        
[text enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])
                         options:NSStringEnumerationByWords
                      usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                                  if ([findMe isEqualToString:substring] ) {
                                      NSLog(@"Found %@", substring);
                                  } else {
                                      NSLog(@"Not found");
                                  }
                              }];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That got me on the right track.
    NSRange found = [substring rangeOfString:text];
is from Apple code, but probably for a different problem than what I'm working with...I'll need to read up more on retain cycles.

Comment: Sure thing.  The gist of it is that blocks retain the variables mentioned in them (like the variable 'text').  And the string being searched retains the block that the caller passes.  So text retains the block which retains text which retains the block, so they kind of lock each other up.

Comment: Got it. I was getting "EXC_BAD ACCESS" crashes before, which seem to have gone away--might have been related to the retain loop. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the block of code is what you want. It loops through each word in the text and you want to find all the search strings. Here is a loop that sets a new search range based on the last successful match.

```
-(void)performSearchWithString:(NSString *)searchString andTexts:(NSSet *)texts
{
for (id book in texts) {
    if ([book isEqual:kBook1]){
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"neiJing" withExtension:@"txt"];
        NSString *text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&error];

        NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [text length]);
        NSRange match = [text rangeOfString:searchString options:0 range:searchRange];
        while (match.location != NSNotFound) {

            // match is the range of the current successful match
            NSLog(@"matching range -- %@", NSStringFromRange(match));

            NSUInteger locationOfNextSearchRange = NSMaxRange(match);
            searchRange = NSMakeRange(locationOfNextSearchRange, [text length] - locationOfNextSearchRange);
            match = [text rangeOfString:searchString options:0 range:searchRange];
        }
    }
}
```